# Finding the number of times characters from text1 occur in text2

Tags: python, for-loop

Write a function definition of occurrences that takes two string arguments. The function returns the number of times a character from the first argument occurs in the second argument.

Example:

`occurrences('fooled', 'hello world')`

should evaluate to:

`7 (1 'e', 3 'l', 2 'o', 1 'd')`

my code is here:

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
"""Return the number of times characters from text1 occur in text2

occurrences(string, string) -> int
"""
# add your code here
ss=0
for c in set(text2):
    if c in text1:
        return text1.count(text2)

return ss
```

It says that:
   Your for loop should iterate over text2 
   Wrong: for the strings 'tc1h' and 'Return the number of times characters from text1        occur in text2' you got 0. The correct answer is 15.'

Comment: Fixing your homework is not "urgent"' and even it it were, it doesn't belong in the question title.

Comment: @Wooble thank you for pointing it out for me. first time posting a question on stackoverflow and i was a bit frustrated so didn't read the guideline thoroughly. btw, can you please help me to some degree? even just a little hint on what i did wrong?

Comment: Here's a hint: how will your code return anything other than `0` if you never add anything to the variable `ss`? (More blatant hint: try changing `return text1.count(text2)` to something like `ss = ss + <SOMETHING YOU NEED TO FIGURE OUT>`)

Comment: Also, you will need to swap `text1` and `text2` if you want to solve the problem that way.

Comment: @Nil Here is a link to a fixed version of your code, with comments explaining most of the lines. Please read the comments so you understand your mistakes rather than just blindly copying it: http://pastebin.com/KNV1yhjv

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in 1 line:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(Counter(c for c in 'hello world' if c in 'fooled').values())
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
"""Return the number of times characters from text1 occur in text2

occurrences(string, string) -> int
"""
text1_dict = {char:0 for char in text1}

for char in text2:
    if char in text1_dict:
        text1_dict[char] += 1

return sum(list(text1_dict.values()))
```

I wrote a code that solves this in O(n) instead of O(n^3)
it makes a dict ouf of text1's chars, that counts occurance of each char in text 2
then it counts text2's chars and update the dict.
finally it returns the sum of the values (unfortunatly you cant do sum on the dict values so i used list before).